# How to write a correct order by case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case

I have this problem, if I'm using the `sql` statement normally, i mean like this:

```
SELECT p.id_plecari, p.id_aeroport, p.id_clasa, p.id_avion, p.data, p.ora, c.pret, av.nume, a.Nume, a.Locatie
    from plecari p, clasa c, avioane av, aeroport a
where 
   p.id_aeroport = a.id_aeroport
   AND p.id_clasa = c.id_clasa
   AND p.id_avion = av.id_avion
   AND p.id_plecari not in(SELECT r.id_plecare from rezervari r WHERE r.id_client = idClient) 
   ORDER BY p.id_clasa ASC;
```

Everything is listed as I expected, perfect like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkfqG.png)
But in the moment when I add the `CASE` statement, everything is messed up:

```
BEGIN
SELECT p.id_plecari, p.id_aeroport, p.id_clasa, p.id_avion, p.data, p.ora, c.pret, av.nume, a.Nume, a.Locatie
    from plecari p, clasa c, avioane av, aeroport a
    where 
        p.id_aeroport = a.id_aeroport
        AND p.id_clasa = c.id_clasa
        AND p.id_avion = av.id_avion
        AND p.id_plecari not in(SELECT r.id_plecare from rezervari r WHERE r.id_client = idClient) ORDER BY 
        (CASE 
    WHEN (orderby = 1 AND orderas = false) THEN p.id_plecari
    WHEN (orderby = 2 AND orderas = false) THEN av.nume
  END) ASC ,
  (CASE 
    WHEN (orderby = 1 AND orderas = true) THEN p.id_plecari
    WHEN (orderby = 2 AND orderas = true) THEN av.nume
  END) DESC;
END
```

Everything looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSaEA.png)!

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`!!!

Comment: As the saying goes, you reap what you sow. Always use explicit `join` syntax for clarity and unabiguity.

Comment: please, teach me master :)) no kidding, i really need an example with this

Comment: `CASE` is an expression. It produces one value (per row, if used in that context) of *one* type, which must be compatible across the type of the expressions in *all* `THEN` clauses. BY trying to combine a string and a number in a single `CASE`, you're forcing everything to be treated as a string.

Comment: I don't get it... Because I'm not familiar with Join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.id_plecari, p.id_aeroport, p.id_clasa, p.id_avion, p.data, p.ora, c.pret, av.nume, a.Nume, a.Locatie
FROM
  plecari   p
INNER JOIN
  clasa     c
    ON p.id_clasa = c.id_clasa
INNER JOIN
  avioane   av
    ON p.id_avion = av.id_avion
INNER JOIN
  aeroport  a
    ON p.id_aeroport = a.id_aeroport
WHERE
  p.id_plecari not in (
    SELECT r.id_plecare from rezervari r WHERE r.id_client = idClient
  )
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN (orderby = 1 AND orderas = false) THEN p.id_plecari END,
  CASE WHEN (orderby = 2 AND orderas = false) THEN av.nume      END,
  CASE WHEN (orderby = 1 AND orderas = true ) THEN p.id_plecari END DESC,
  CASE WHEN (orderby = 2 AND orderas = true ) THEN av.nume      END DESC;
```

This shows how to use `JOIN`, and how to break your `ORDER BY` in to parts.

Note, however, that the performance of this style of "conditional ordering" can be very poor.

This is because the database has to generate a single execution plan to fulfil all possibilities.

The more performance approach is to have the main query as a view, then have something akin to...

```
IF (orderby = 1 AND orderas = false) THEN
  SELECT * FROM yourView ORDER BY p.id_plecari;
ELSEIF (orderby = 2 AND orderas = false) THEN
  SELECT * FROM yourView ORDER BY av.nume;
ELSEIF (orderby = 1 AND orderas = true) THEN
  SELECT * FROM yourView ORDER BY p.id_plecari DESC;
ELSEIF (orderby = 2 AND orderas = true) THEN
  SELECT * FROM yourView ORDER BY av.nume DESC;
ENDIF;
```

This allows a different execution plan for each sorting pattern.

- [This](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) explains it in more detail